# 一片空地 and 一片草原 - what's the difference/relation

Tags: difference

Can anyone explain what the difference or relation between 一片空地 and 一片草原 might be?

Are these two expressions the same?

Comment: They are different. 空地 means space with nothing, clearing. 草原 means grasslands.

Comment: These are not expressions. They mean what they mean literally. Have you tried a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“一片草原” - obviously there must be grass growing there;

[image: 草原]

“一片空地” - just open space/ground without any building or trees, so you can put something there or build something there, or even play baseball there.

[image: 空地1]
[image: 空地2]

Answer (score 1):

“一片草原”得有草才能这么说吧，“一片空地”通常指没有建筑或没有摆放其他东西

Comment: It's better to give the explanation in English, if the question was asked by English.

Comment: @songyuanyao I'm sorry,my English is poorer than your Chinese.

Comment: Chinese is ok for an answer. This is a Chinese language site.